# Selecting dates from today and beyond

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I have a SQL query that I seem to be having issues with. It is working fine when I run it directly against the table (in SQL Server Management Studio). However, when I plug it into my ColdFusion (old I know) it's spitting out different results.

I believe the blame here lays with the `getdate()` function, but I'm not sure a way around it.

When I run this in SQL I'm getting back 53 results, which is correct.

```
SELECT *
FROM CMS.dbo.Settings
Inner Join CMS.dbo.Sites on CMS.dbo.Settings.ID = CMS.dbo.Sites.ID
WHERE CMS.dbo.Settings.EndDate >= getdate()
AND CMS.dbo.Sites.Active = 1
```

As soon as I plug that into a cfquery. I am getting a record count of two (2) results. Is there something I need to do to make this more cf specific? I haven't done CF in a long time.

Comment: (Edit) Since there are no CF variables involved, CF simply passes that SQL off to your database for execution. So there should not be any difference in the result from SSMS and CF - beyond the few seconds that elapsed in between your tests. Whether that is relevant depends on the data itself. I would start by a) verifying the results are repeatable and b) checking the actual dates and times of the "missing" 51 records to see if there is a valid reason. ...

Comment: Are they excluded because the dates were only few seconds/minutes in the future? Were the records modified in the interim, ecetera, ...? c) On the CF side, is the cfquery cached?

Comment: To test Leigh's theorys, replace getDate() with a hard coded value and see if the results are the same.

Comment: @Leigh I have checked all the dates and they are all well into the future. 2018 and above. So I know that is not an issue and that is why I did not have the query go down to the second.

Comment: @DanBracuk I have hard coded today's date and receive the same thing. I am running the same query in cf as I am in sql server management and am receiving different results.

Comment: @zazvorniki - What happens when you replace the `select *` with `select columnA, columnB....`?

Comment: Could be that you are querying different databases, or am I the only person who does that?

Comment: Umm... nope... um... only you Dan ;-)

Comment: ....You are not alone Dan....you are not alone. I was querying qa when I should have been on prod. And this is why it's scary having me work in the database...

Answer (score 0):

it is weird. check cfquery tag, if it has maxrows just in case.

Comment: There is no maxrows in the tag.

Comment: just curious: why you have DELEGATES in your query whereas your JOIN should be on CMS.dbo.Settings.  **FROM CMS.dbo.Settings
Inner Join CMS.dbo.Sites on DELEGATES.dbo.Settings.ID = CMS.dbo.Sites.ID**

Comment: Because I was trying to edit out my actual table names for posting here and forgot to edit one.

Answer (score 0):

Check all the settings in your DSN. You may have something a bit off in there. You're welcome to post a screen shot of the Advanced screen for us to check out.